# Why don't add the ngClass the class parameter to the html tag, but the condition is true in Angular template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have this code in my Angular template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of product.names; let index of index" [ngClass]="{'text-muted': index === 0}">
  {{ name.value }}
</div>
```

Then it's generate this HTML code in browser for the first element of `names` array:

```html
<div _ngcontent-drs-c6="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> Test </div>
```

Why don't add the `class` parameter to the `div` if the condition is true? Where is the mistake in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `let i = index"`

```
<div *ngFor="let name of product.names; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'text-muted':  i === 0}">
    {{ name.value }}
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9x5ggp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[class.text-muted]="index === 0"
```

Comment: I want to use the `ngClass` method, because here will be multiple class based on multiple conditions.

Comment: Add comments which would explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because `let index of index`. It is not correct. Correct syntax is `let i = index`. So try to rewrite like this:

```
<div *ngFor = "let name of product.names; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"
    [ngClass]="{'text-muted': i === 0}"> 
</div>
```

[The work stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-yhdwfu?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: I want to use the `ngClass` method, because here will be multiple class based on multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of product.names; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'text-muted': i === 0}">
  {{ name.value }}
</div>
```